# Error on creating DataTemplate in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm trying to create a DataTemplate in code behind with the following:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
    @"<DataTemplate      
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:Clarity.Demo.ListDragDrop;assembly=Clarity.Demo.ListDragDrop"">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
           <local:PlayerAdorner x:Key=""adorner""/>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <local:PlayerControl 
            Margin=""5""
            local:DragDropHelper.AdornerLayer = ""adornLayer""
            local:DragDropHelper.DragDropControl = ""{StaticResource adorner}""
            local:DragDropHelper.DropTarget = ""lineup""
            local:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource = ""true"" />
        </DataTemplate > ");

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
DataTemplate laneTemplate = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
```

I get an XAML exception saying that 'x' is a space for a non declared name in line 5. I guess there's something wrong with `x:Key=""adorner""`, but it's strange because if instead of creating this in code I copy it and paste on the XAML it works!

I'm not sure this is the right way of doing it. The original code had the adorner resource in Window.Resources, but I didn't figured out how to access it when creating the DataTemplate in code, so I put it as a DataTemplate.Resource.

Does anyone have any clue on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the namespace:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```